# How do you embed a form within a form for infopath 2013

Tags: infopath

I need to embed a child form into a parent form within infopath 2013. Does anyone know how to do this??

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported (as you cannot embed  tag inside and  tag. Not sure what is your use case but I assume you need to update another list. If you are on prem you could use code behind to update another list using custom code.